# 'string' does not contain a definition for/

Tags: c#

**Error**:
 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedPath' and no extension method 'SelectedPath' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

**Code**:

```
 private static string fbd = String.Empty;
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.Description = "Select a Folder to save the images.";
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
    }

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> address = new List<string>();
        Random r = new Random();
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600000_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600001_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600002_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600003_460s.jpg");
        //MessageBox.Show(address[r.Next(0, 4)]);

        if (comboBox1.Text == "10")
        {
            string filename = fbd.SelectedPath;
            MessageBox.Show(fbd);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(address[r.Next(0, 4)]));
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {

                using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead != 0);
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(address[r.Next(0, 25)], filename);
                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

**Explanation**:
For button3_Click im trying to get it to call the save location you set to save the image. I have looked all over the net and im not finding a way to fix this :/

I also am getting an error when i manually enter a save location.
Access to the path 'H:\images' is denied.
And no the folder is not read only. It gives me the same error no matter where i set the save location.

Comment: Oh man, I just looked at one of your images fro your code and wished I hadn't, amde me laugh though !

Comment: @MattRoberts LOL was it the first one?

Comment: @MattRoberts worried to check in case it's nsfw xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fdb is a string. You have declared a class-wide field called fdb of type string, which doesn't have the property SelectedPath

In yout button2_click method, you have a File Dialog that presumably you want to access instead, so you need to declare that in the class-wide scope instead.

```
private FolderBrowserDialog _fbDlg;
private static string fbd = String.Empty; // Do you really need this?
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _fbDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        _fbDlg.Description = "Select a Folder to save the images.";
        if (_fbDlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = _fbDlg.SelectedPath;
    }

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> address = new List<string>();
        Random r = new Random();
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600000_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600001_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600002_460s.jpg");
        address.Add("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4600003_460s.jpg");
        //MessageBox.Show(address[r.Next(0, 4)]);

        if (comboBox1.Text == "10")
        {
            string filename = _fbDlg.SelectedPath;
```

Comment: Ahh i see, i had private static string fbd = String.Empty;  so i could use the variable in button3_click, still new to C#, now just to figure out why all my save locations are getting denied assess to

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have declared two variables with the same name - `fbd`:

```
private static string fbd = String.Empty;

FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
```

Rename one of them to avoid confusion. Then I think you will be able to figure out the correct solution to your problem.